# HTTP Post using Thread

Tags: php, android, multithreading, http-post, server

I want to send string using HTTP Post Method To a Server`(www.000webhost.com)`using thread method in Android.But unfortunately it is not responding`HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://192.168.2.1:53811/WinnerSite/WebService.asm/MyMethod

```
try {
    // Add your data
    List nameValuePairs = new ArrayList(2);
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("json", name));
  //  nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("stringdata", "AndDev is Cool!"));
    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

    // Execute HTTP Post Request
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);`
```

Comment: have you verified that, this server is live and running ?

Comment: What is `not responding` ? Is there a connection?  If there is a timeout you will have an exception. Please tell where your code goes. Show the logcat. Device or emulator?